# How to set a limit to servo value as python variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

I am controlling a servo motor through my web app. I have 2 buttons, left and right. When each of them is click, the servo should turn slightly to left or right according to the button. I am using jQuery `.post()` function to post to a python function `turnCamera`. 
My question here is as follow:

How do I make sure the limit of the servo value will not get exceeded and there is no need to reset the value of `m` everytime i call the function? From my script, I think the value of `m` will get reset to 1500 everytime it is called, which is will cause the servo to turn to only 2 positions! The neutral position (90 degree) is 1500. The min and max value of `m` is 500 and 2500 respectively. Any value beyond that range will cause harm to my servo. 
Also, will the python actually run like that? How can i see the output from `print`? Is what i'm doing using the `done` function correct?

Here is part of my HTML and jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#left_button').click(function(){
            $.post('cameraservo.py/turnCamera', {direction:"left"}).done(function (reply) {
                $('#camerapos').html(reply)});
        });
        $('#right_button').click(function(){
            $.post('cameraservo.py/turnCamera', {direction:"right"}).done(function (reply) {
                $('#camerapos').html(reply)});
        });
    });
</script>

 <div id="control_button">
    <img src="button_left.png" id="left_button" height="50" width="50">
    <img src="button_right.png" id="right_button" height="50" width="50">
 </div>
```

My Python code:

```
def turnCamera (self, **data):

import pigpio
import time

# import serial
# def servo_control(command):
    # serialport= serial.Serial ("/dev/ttyACM0", 9600, timeout=0.5)
    # serialport.write(command)
    # return serialport.readlines(1)

servos=[4]
key = data['direction']

m=1500 #what to do with this??
while (m >= 500 and m <= 2500):
    if key="left":
        m=m+100
    else if key="right":
        m=m-100

pigpio.start()

pigpio.set_servo_pulsewidth(servos[0], m) 
print("Servo {} {} micro pulses".format(servos[0], key, m))
time.sleep(1)

pigpio.stop()
```

Much thanks!

Comment: You have two rather unrelated questions. They should be separate questions on stackoverflow, too.

Comment: How is it unrelated? you mean the URL part? Okay, I will remove that. thank you.