# How jQuery do POST to a python function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

I tried to find a sample using POST from jQuery to Python but I only found answers that use ajax. Here is my jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#left_button').click(function(){
            $.post('cameraservo.py/turnCamera', {direction:"left"})
        });
        $('#right_button').click(function(){
            $.post('cameraservo.py/turnCamera', {direction:"right"})
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here is my python file:

```
def turnCamera (self, **data):

import pigpio
import time

# import serial
# def servo_control(command):
    # serialport= serial.Serial ("/dev/ttyACM0", 9600, timeout=0.5)
    # serialport.write(command)
    # return serialport.readlines(1)

servos=[4]
key = data['direction']

m=1500
while (m >= 500 and m <= 2500):
    if key="left":
        m=m+100
    else if key="right":
        m=m-100

pigpio.start()

pigpio.set_servo_pulsewidth(servos[0], m) 
servostatus= "Servo {} {} micro pulses".format(servos[0], key, m)
print servostatus
time.sleep(1)

pigpio.stop()

return servostatus
```

Is my post URL format correct? i.e. `$.post('cameraservo.py/turnCamera'`
I have another question regarding this program at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21901490/how-to-set-a-limit-to-servo-value-as-python-variable?noredirect=1#comment33168135_21901490). thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set absolute url to fetch an URL.
EG: `$.post('http://www.cameraservo.py/turnCamera', {direction: 'left'});`

You will need to setup [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) on your Python Server ([example here](https://gist.github.com/enjalot/2904124)) to allow xmlHttpRequest requests from others domains.

Comment: but it's not http://www... it's just a python file residing in the same directory as the html file. does it really have to be so complicated?

Comment: In this case, your URL format is ok and you don't need CORS.
So... no issue here :-)